# How to know if a module is installed in node

Tags: node.js

I know that I can install a module in node.js using `npm install module-name`. but try that multiiple times and it will install again. I am tired of forgetting that I have installed modules globally and I am installing them again. How do I know if a module installation already exists globally in node?

Comment: It doesn't actually install again. It just checks to see if it has been updated on NPM. If not, nothing is downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

you have to try

```
npm ls
```

will give you the list of installed modules

to list global packages

```
npm ls -g
```

to list global packages with more detail

```
npm ls -gl
```

same way to list local packages with detail

```
npm ls -l
```

also you can type

```
npm help ls
```

for more details regarding this

Answer (score 2):

in your js code, just do this:

```
try {
    console.log(require.resolve("some-npm-module-name"));
} catch(e) {
    console.error('moduel is not installed');
    process.exit(e.code);
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether you have a specific module installed, you can run `npm explore <module>`. If you get an error, then you don't have that module and you should download it.

This is a bit of a hack, but it works.